# Understanding the 2-norm inequality for commuting orthogonal subspaces of traceless matrices in direct sum

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, direct-sum, closed-graph

I am trying to investigate following problem (not only to prove it or disprove it in its current form, but also learn a "context" around it).

Let $A, B$ be vector spaces of traceless matrices such that A is orthogonal to B (in Frobenius inner product sense) and $S = \{ a + b\ |\ a \in A, b \in B \}$ is an internal direct sum. Moreover $A, B$ commute, meaning that for $a \in A, b \in B$ we have $ab = ba$.

I am interested in proving (or disproving) following inequality:

$$
\lVert s \rVert_2^2 \leq  \lVert a \rVert_2^2 + \lVert b \rVert_2^2
$$
where: $\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$ is matrix 2-norm (its biggest singular value).

We already know that without commuting property the inequality does not hold: [Relationship between matrix 2-norm of internal direct sum and orthogonal vector spaces of traceless matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4689391/relationship-between-matrix-2-norm-of-internal-direct-sum-and-orthogonal-vector).

But, while browsing through the math.stackexchange.com I found following [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3916160/internal-and-orthogonal-direct-sum-isomorphic-in-hilbert-spaces), that asks similar question and gets positive answer. I do not have great grasp on functional analysis, so I might be very well misunderstanding something. But combining following part about [direct sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3916168/1124789)

> whenever a Banach space $X$ is the (algebraic) direct sum of two closed subspaces $E$ and $F$, then the natural projections $\pi_E$ and $\pi_F$ are continuous.  Therefore, for every $x$ in $E$, the new norm
> $$
>    |||x||| = \|\pi_E(x)\| + \|\pi_F(x)\|
>    $$
> is equivalent to the original norm on $X$

And this comment about [equivalent but not equal norms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3916160/internal-and-orthogonal-direct-sum-isomorphic-in-hilbert-spaces#comment8076465_3916168):

> Equivalent norms need not be equal! It is enough that $A\lVert x \rVert \leq \lVert \lvert x \rVert \rvert \leq B \lVert x \rVert$
> , for all x
> . And yes, the norm need not come from an inner product, but if would would like it to be just define it as $|||x|||=(∥π_E(x)∥^2+∥π_F(x)∥^2)^{1/2}$
> and everythig else will be just the same.

My questions are as follows:

1. Do I need "only" to find projections such that $\pi_E$ and $\pi_F$, such that $\lVert \pi_E(A) \rVert_2 \leq \lVert A \rVert_2, \lVert \pi_F(B) \rVert_2 \leq \lVert B \rVert_2$
2. Do I need to find such that $\pi_E$ and $\pi_F$ that $(\lVert \pi_E(A) \rVert_2 + \lVert \pi_F(B) \rVert_2)^2 \leq \lVert A \rVert_2^2 + \lVert B \rVert_2^2$
3. Am I missing the mark completely?

Comment: The inequality is not true. E.g. when $a$ is the $4\times4$ permutation matrix for a cyclic shift and $b=a^2$, we have $ab=ba$ and $\langle a,b\rangle_F=\operatorname{tr}(a^Tb)=\operatorname{tr}(a)=0$ but $\|a+b\|_2^2=2^2>1^2+1^2=\|a\|_2^2+\|b\|_2^2$. Now take $A$ and $B$ as the linear spans of $a$ and $b$ respectively and you obtain a counterexample.